# How can i delete files from archive directory

Tags: linux, postgresql, archive, wal

**Directory Path:**

`/var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/lib/pgsql/archive`

Count:

```
-bash-4.2$ ls -lrt | wc -l
3839
-bash-4.2$ ls -lrt *backup | wc -l
14
```

Example of file created: `000000010000000000000001`

Can I delete older files? will it impact current db functioning
Can I move these old file in any other directory? will it impact current db functioning

Answer (score 0):

Deleting WAL archives will not impede database functionality, but it will limit which backup you can still restore.

You can use `pg_archivecleanup` to delete all WAL segments older than a certain one, or you could delete them once they exceed a certain age.

It makes no sense to keep around WAL archives that are older than your oldest base backup, so you might take that as your guideline. On the other hand, you should never delete WAL archives that are still required to restore a backup you want to retain.

If the archives were written with `archive_command`, the job is simple: The directory then will also contain `*.backup` files from your base backups. Just use the file from the oldest backup you want to retain with `pg_archivecleanup`.